# The Geometry Shader is duplicating Shapes (in Processing)

Tags: opengl, glsl, processing, geometry-shader

I'm trying to generate a simple shape with a Geometry Shader, but the shape is rendering twice and I don't know why.

First we have a really simple Vertex Shader

```
#version 150

in vec4 position;
 
void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
}
```

Then there's a Geometry Shader thats generating a simple triangle.

```
#version 150

layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 5) out;
 
out FragData {
  vec4 color;
} FragOut;
 
void main(){

  //RED TOP LEFT
  FragOut.color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 
  gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4( -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  EmitVertex();

  //BLUE BOTTOM LEFT
  FragOut.color = vec4(0., 0., 1., 1.);
  gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4( -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  EmitVertex();

  //GREEN BOTTOM RIGHT
  FragOut.color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4( 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  EmitVertex();

  EndPrimitive();
}
```

And finally a simple Fragment Shader

```
#version 150

in FragData {
  vec4 color;
} FragIn;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {
  fragColor = FragIn.color;
}
```

The result should be a triangle, but TWO triangles are being rendered:

[Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU0Vi.png)

Comment: The geometry shader is executed once for each primitive. How many primitives do you draw? 2?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. I'm using the shader on a Processing rectangle. Here's the full code: https://github.com/PauRosello97/Formorgel-Shaders. Thank you.

Comment: `rect(0, 0, width, height);` does this draw a rectangle? If so, you are drawing two triangles. And you calculate all coordinates using the first vertex position. So everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

The [Geometry Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader) is executed once for each primitive. A [`rect()`](https://processing.org/reference/rect_.html) consists of 2 triangles, so the geometry shader is executed twice and generates 2 `triangle_strip` primitives.

Draw a single `POINTS` primitive instead of the rectangle:

```java
beginShape(POINTS);
vertex(x, y);
endShape();
```

Note that you need to change the [Primitive input specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Primitive_in.2Fout_specification):

<s>`layout (triangles) in;`</s>

```c
layout (points) in;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sure this is the way, but I get an error when I change the Primitive input specification: OpenGL error 1282 at bot endDraw(): invalid operation